# How to fill a specific area with a certain color?

Tags: python, pygame

So I want to figure out to only fill the bottom part of my background green. However, since I just started Pygame I don't actually know what code there is for filling in backgrounds except for `screen.fill()`.

This is my display size:

```py
displayW = 700
displayH = 700
```

Answer (score 2):

See [`pygame.Surface.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill):

> ```
> fill(color, rect=None, special_flags=0) -> Rect
> ```

Use the `rect` argument. e.g.:

```py
screen.fill(color, rect = (0, 400, 700, 300))
```

Alternatively draw a rectangle with [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect). e.g.:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (0, 400, 700, 300))
```